# Get hash of submodule at previous version of main repo without checking out

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo which a submodule in it.

I can get the current hash of the submodule from the working directory easily:

```
cd submodule
git rev-list HEAD | head -n 1
```

However i am also interested in the hash at previous versions of the main repo. I can get it if i actually check out that version:

```
git checkout some_tag
cd submodule
git rev-list HEAD | head -n 1
```

However, i cannot use *git checkout*. Is there a way to obtain that hash without checking out the old tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `git rev-parse` (which is also the correct tool for reading the value of `HEAD`):

```
git rev-parse some_tag:submodule
```

This reads the *gitlink* entry from the *tree object* to which `some_tag` can be resolved, using the supplied path.  To see how it works, use:

```
tree=$(git rev-parse some_tag^{tree})
git ls-tree -r $tree
```

(the `-r` option is only required if the submodule path is not at the top level of the repository).  Note that the tree entry for the submodule is simply `160000 commit <hash> <path>`: this is how the superproject knows which commit hash ID to use in the submodule.

Comment: btw `some_tag:` is short for `some_tag^{tree}`.