# How to get all the submodule hashes recursively for an older commit of the Repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to get all the submodule versions (hashes) for each submodule recursively.

`git submodule status --recursive` does it well but only for HEAD...

I am looking for a solution to get the sema result for an older commit or reference.

So what I need is something like that:

```
git submodule status --recursive <commitHash>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hash of submodule at previous version of main repo without checking out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392802/get-hash-of-submodule-at-previous-version-of-main-repo-without-checking-out)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+without+checkout

Comment: Can you try [foreach](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt)